# Finding a specific file in a folder in java

Tags: java

I need to find a specific file for example, info.txt in a folder. The problem is I do not know under what level the file is. For example, the file can be in a sub-folder or in a sub-folder of a sub-folder.

So this means I have to go through recursion.... Or there is a simple way to complete this task. I am using JDK 1.5.

Comment: Recursion is the way to go, but consider this: do you return the first occurrence of `info.txt` you find?

Comment: Yes, I shall return the first occurrence of info.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use recursion, but its a good idea. You can use the `File` object in java to help you along. A couple of the key things you will be using:

- the `isDirectory()` function. Fairly self explanatory.
- If the `File` object is a directory, you will have to use the `listFiles()` function. Returns an array of file objects which are files AND directories. You just call your recursive function on this array.
- You might also want to look into the [FilenameFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) interface to help you along.

A simple mock up of the code would be something like

```
File findFile(String fileName, File[] files){
    for(File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory) File f = findFile(fileName, file.listFiles());
        if(f!=null) return f;
        if(file.getName.equals(fileName)) return file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apache commons-io FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). Assuming you want to recursively search for file **foo** under directory **messyfolder**:

```
Collection<File> results = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("messyfolder"), 
                                               new NameFileFilter("foo"), 
                                               TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC java 7 had some directory walking utils. You can also use a stack or a queue to walk a directory tree without recursion.

Comment: some more details in your answer would be helpful